# HelloRMIServer cannot connect in bind()

Tags: java, rmi

Doing a course, and I am trying to wrap my head around RMI. I cant seem to get it right. Link to unmodified source code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7NQABLlsgGWbXNhb0JHall4NXM

```
package helloworld;

import java.rmi.Naming;

public class HelloRMIServer {

// TODO 08. Set the OBJECT_NAME to the same value used by the client.
private static String OBJECT_NAME = "TEST";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // TODO 09. Create a new instance of the remote object.
        MessageInterface message = new MessageInterface();
        // TODO 10. Re-bind the object in the registry.
        Naming.rebind("rmi://" + "127.0.0.1" + "/" + OBJECT_NAME, message);
        System.out.println("Server object message bound into registry.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Server done creating and binding objects.");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message? It would be helpful if you can provide a stack trace.

Comment: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connectServer done creating and binding objects.

 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)

Comment: The two things I am having issue with are the line that starts off: MessageInterface message = null; // TODO 09. Create a new instance of the remote object.                                                                                                and               // TODO 10. Re-bind the object in the registry.

Comment: No. You only posted one stack trace, not two, and it comes from the second of those, which shows that you aren't having any trouble with the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't started the `rmiregistry`.